# Command Line call for Reliability Monitor

Tags: command-line

Does anyone know how to call and display the Reliability Monitor via command line?

I'm able to display the Security and Maintenance via:
control /name Microsoft.SecurityCenter

But I can't discover the call for 
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Security and Maintenance\Reliability Monitor

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command-line for the Reliability Monitor is:

```
perfmon /rel
```